# React state resets when calling an async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to display a loader in react then execute an async function and then removing the loader but seems like the loader disappears as soon as the function starts executing.

Here's a sample code:

```
const component = () => {
    const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(false)
    
    const clickHandler = async (status: string) => {
        setShowLoader(true)
        const success = await someAsyncFunction()
        success ? setShowLoader(false) : true
    }

    return (<div hidden={!showLoader}><Loader /></div>)
}
```

[Edit] Here is a simplified version of my someAsyncFunction:

```
const someAsyncFunction = async() => {
    for (let i=0;i < 99999;i++){
        console.log(i)
    }
    return Promise.Resolve(true)
}
```

It is evident that someAsyncFunction does return resolve the Promise and no sooner as it executes the loop for about 100K times

Comment: Are you sure `someAsyncFunction` works properly? Seems to me it might resolve the promise too early (or not return one at all). How do you know that the loader is hidden too early?

Comment: someAsyncFunction is in a seperate .ts file doing no operation on the showLoader state whatsoever

Comment: it does some calculation and return a Promise resolved with either true or false

Comment: *"it does some calculation"* What does it do exactly?

Comment: @FelixKling I did a debug... After setting the state and before calling the function, it shows up the Loader but once the function starts it disappears

Comment: it should be `async` not `await` keyword before the function.and the `resolve` is with lowercase

Comment: the way you are implementing the `someAsyncFunction` is not how promises work.the `someAsyncFunction` above will block the execution before reaching to the return statement so the flow is synchronous not async.

Comment: @KeyvanKh In actual case I've some API calls in place of loop... Here just to mimic the delay, I've introduced the loop. So that it doesn't resolve the promise too early

Comment: if you want to resemble a promise you should use something like `settimeout` and return a promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the nature of useState hook, it doesn't set the value instantly instead it's sort of a request queue. In this case, before the state is update, the function is called.

Best approach would be to use an useffect hook with the showLoader as it's dependency, and execute the function within it as it ensures the execution only after the state is set

Answer (score 0):

Hey from what I see there, Your the bang `!` your using changes the state your using if `it's true it will false and vice-versa`

so I suggest you do this instead. if hidden is `false` the loading will be seen. if the functions is a success you turn hidden to `true` else it will keep showing **Loader**

```
const component = () => {
    const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(false)
    
    const clickHandler = async (status: string) => {
        const success = await someAsyncFunction()
        success ? setShowLoader(true) : null
    }

    return (<div hidden={showLoader}><Loader /></div>)
}
```

Comment: How !showLoader will change the state if setShowLoader isn't executed?

Comment: !false = true if that is true then I hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

inside the `clickHandler` funciton you are declaring a statement
`success ? setShowLoader(false) : true`.
the engine would reach this code after executing the `someAsyncfunction`. at this point the `success` is just a promise it has't `fulfilled` yet.the statement is true then the `setShowloader` will execute and set the loader to hide.a simple solution is to put `await` keyword befor `success` inside that statement.this is how we tell the engine that execute the statement whenever the  success is `fulfilled` or `rejcted`.

```
 (await success) ? setShowLoader(false) : true
```

Comment: I'm already awaiting the response from async function and the control won't flow unless the promise is settled